# Installing Linux without recreating the previously created partitions

Tags: boot, multi-boot, partition-recovery, boot-partition, bootrepair

Tried to install Linux but during installation it's not recognizing the previously installed Windows and Linux OS. When creating partition, it is displaying entire hard drive as one partition.. any way to recover the partitions without rewriting any of the files.

Answer (score 0):

Check TestDisk (http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk).  It should be able to recover partitions.